# Django CMS dynamic templates forlder for mobile

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a Django CMS 2.4 website and currently when detecting mobile user agent I switch to a different URL settings and serving different pages for mobile. Now I would like to use same content for both but to use different template for mobile and desktop versions so I don't need to do edits in two places and so the URL will stay the same for both. I know it would be easy to do in Django, but having Django CMS I have no control over rendering and template selection. Can I do it in any way, or should I look for a different solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django CMS will check if there is an `template` variable in POST or GET in request, and if it's a valid template (it's set up in `CMS_TEMPLATES` in `options.py`), it will be used to display page. 
The following snippet can be used in `middleware.py` for switching templates:

```
if request.COOKIES.get("mobi")=='y':
        if request.current_page:
            request.POST._mutable = True
            request.POST['template'] = 'mobile/' + get_template_from_request(request)
            request.POST._mutable = False
```

One thing you need to remember, this will only switch templates for `page`, to change a template for plugin you need to modify `instance.template` variable in `render` method of plugin.